# Immediate Effect of Update Domain Name Server

Tags: domain, hosting, web-hosting, web

For changing the Hosting of any domain we have to update the name server of domain and it took approx 24 hours to reflect the changes on domain of new hosting. 
My question is that , Is this possible that if we change the Name server and it will reflect with immediate effect and the domain will run from the new hosting ?

For example :

```
Website 1 ---> Hosting 1
```

if we want

```
Website 1 ---> Hosting 2 (it could take 24 hours to reflect)
```

is this time can be reduce ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future, lower the DNS record's TTL prior to the migration.

Comment: sorry not getting you properly, can elaborate more specifically ?

Comment: You set the value of the TTL property for the DNS record that you are changing to a lower value. It sounds like it's set to 24 hours now. Set to to 5 minutes at least a day before the next time you do this. If you have no idea what a TTL is, start by reading this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Record_caching

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you pls tell me to change TTL value will make any problematic effect ? suppose i change it to 24 hours to 1 hour ?

Comment: You may want to ask your supervisor for some training materials. Asking "How does DNS work?" (which is essentially what this question is) is not what Server Fault is for. Try to help yourself before you ask others for help.